# node-cron - Deprecation warning: imediateStart is deprecated and will be removed

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I updated nodejs from 8 to 10.12 and receive that warning message.

```
D:\BitBucket\EA Studio>node index
DEPRECIATION: imediateStart is deprecated and will be removed soon in favor of the options param.
...
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
}
```

Usage:

```
"use strict";

const cron = require("node-cron");
cron.schedule("5 * * * *", () => null, false);
```

Any solutions?

Since I don't use `imediateStart` in my code, the warning origin must be within the internal code of the `node-cron`. Do the developers made that to not forget to update their own code? how much better would be to show: "This version of node-cron uses deprecated code. Please update it to version xxx as soon as it is released".

Comment: Google? First result: https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/issues/100

Comment: Yes, you are right. the warning comes from node-cron. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
cron.schedule("5 * * * *", () => null, false);
```

with

```
cron.schedule("5 * * * *", () => null, {scheduled:false});
```

From `node-cron` documentation on `schedule` method:

> **options** Object: Optional configuration for job scheduling.
>
> Options
>
> **scheduled**: A boolean to set if the created task is schaduled. Default true;
>
> **timezone**: The timezone that is used for job scheduling;

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with `--trace-warnings` flag. eg.: `node --trace-warnings index.js`. It will give you a detailed info what causes the warning.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately nothing useful. I have the same deprecation  warning message.